Tangent line and normal line to a curve
In exercise 1.1.9 of Elementary Differential Geometry by Pressley, it's asked that given a curve $\gamma(t) = (2\cos t-\cos 2t, 2\sin t-\sin 2t)$, find its tangent and normal lines at $t=\pi/4$.
Given a curve $\gamma(t) = (2\cos t-\cos 2t, 2\sin t-\sin 2t)$, its tangent is $\dot{\gamma}(t) = (-2\sin t+2\sin 2t, 2\cos t-2\cos 2t)$. Their values at $t=\pi/4$ are $\gamma(\pi/4) = (\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}-1)$ and $\dot{\gamma}(\pi/4) = \sqrt{2} (\sqrt{2}-1,1)$. The norm $\lVert\dot{\gamma}(\pi/4)\rVert = 2 \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$ is the slope of the tangent line at $t=\pi/4$.
At $t=\pi/4$, the tangent line is $y-(\sqrt{2}-1) = 2 \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}} (x-\sqrt{2})$, while the normal line is $y-(\sqrt{2}-1) = -\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}} (x-\sqrt{2})$.
Question 1. Pressley's answer is, the tangent line is $y-(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-1) = \frac{(x-\sqrt{2})}{\sqrt{2}-1}$, while the normal line is $y-(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-1) = -(x-\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{2}-1)$. Is this an error and my calculations are correct or am I mistaken?
I have plotted both my answer and Pressley's answer, and it seems like Pressley's answer doesn't even make sense. The curve is depicted in blue, the tangent line is depicted in green, the normal line is depicted in orange, and the value $\gamma(\pi/4) = (\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}-1)$ of the curve at $t=\pi/4$ is depicted by a red dot.

Question 2. Assuming my answer is correct, as I know the normal line should be perpendicular to the tangent line, but as can be seen in my plot, they don't seem to be perpendicular to each other. Why is that?
I also noticed similar posts 895158 1683511 to which only one has commented on the inconsistency but did not expand further.
Edit: As advised by the commenter @Red Five, the answer to Question 2 is that I forgot to fix the scale of the plot so it seems like the tangent and normal lines aren't perpendicular, but after fixing the scale, they are indeed perpendicular as shown below. However, Question 1 still remains.


To answer Question 2, the scale looks different in your two axes, hence angles do not appear their actual size.

@RedFive Silly me, I'll update my answer. Thanks!

Looking at the two diagrams, it looks (not certain, just looks) as though a negative sign may be the only difference between the two answers.

@RedFive I know what you mean, probably a minus sign would flip the tangent and normal lines or "rotate" them so as to touch the red dot. Although I'm not sure how Pressley has written the forms of the tangent and normal lines. Some posters in other threads that I've linked wrote solutions that align with Pressley's answer, though it make some sense, still the final answer poses an issue as shown in my plot of Pressley's answer.

Yours looks correct so why worry about question 1?

@Paul Just wanted to confirm this issue, since other posters in other threads I've linked posted answers aligning with Pressley's answer, so I just thought of the possibility of me missing something obvious or trivial. On the other hand, if my answer is correct, this may be helpful in the future for others when they also encounter this exercise.

The norm of the derivative is not the slope of the tangent line! The slope of the tangent line is the ratio of the $y$ to $x$ coordinates of the derivative. The norm of the derivative is the speed of the point $\gamma(t)$ is moving with respect to $t$. So you got the slope wrong while Pressley got the point wrong. Probably when Pressley calculated the point, they inadvertently dropped the $2$ from $2\sin t$.

@PaulSinclair I see, I have plotted it again and the correct solution looks very similar to my plot but the tangent and normal lines are slightly rotated. What Pressley used for the point is $\gamma(\pi/4) = (\sqrt{2}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-1)$, he actually missed a factor of 2 in the y-coordinate as you said, it should actually be $\gamma(\pi/4) = (\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}-1)$. If you can please write your response as an answer, I'd gladly accept it. Thanks!
